# How to convert Word to images with win32com in python?

Tags: python, windows, image, ms-word

I have googled an example for converting Word to Html.

```
import win32com 
from win32com.client import Dispatch, constants  
w = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application') 
w = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Word.Application')

'''skip some code here'''

wc = win32com.client.constants 
w.ActiveDocument.SaveAs( FileName = filenameout, FileFormat = wc.wdFormatHTML )
```

I tried looking for something like `wc.wdFormatPNG` as `wc.wdFormatHTML` in the example but failed.And I wonder does the attribute exist?Or any other better solutions?Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print the Word document to PDF or [TIFF file](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP010278581033.aspx). I never did it myself, but if it can be done manually, most probably you can automate it.